# ffmpeg получить из видео, звуковую дорожку в формате wav

Tags: ffmpeg

Чтобы получить звуковую дорожку из видео, прибегаю к

```
ffmpeg -i $file -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 -async 48000  $path"/6-mp3/wa_.wav"
```

Файл конвертируется, но неверно. В конце выдает

```
[ac3 @ 0x71ace0] incomplete framebitrate=1535.8kbits/s speed= 219x
[wav @ 0x6f1560] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 354476544, current: 0; changing to 354476544. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[wav @ 0x6f1560] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 354476544, current: 1568; changing to 354476544. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[wav @ 0x6f1560] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 354476544, current: 1591; changing to 354476544. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

В результате при использования сконвертированного файла, для дальнейшей обработки формата wav. Мне не удается сделать это, поскольку при данных ошибках, другое приложение не хочет его читать.

Comment: Выручайте... Форматы видео разные, из каждого необходим wav файл без ошибок, иначе стороннее приложение не прочитает его

Comment: Ещё `-vn` добавь спереди

Comment: `ffmpeg -i $file -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 -async 48000 -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1  -acodec pcm_s16le -vn "$path/2.wav"`

Comment: За счет (aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1) удалось убрать нижние строчки, осталась только верхняя. Файл по прежнему невозможно работать в pyton

Comment: `[ac3 @ 0x71ace0] incomplete framebitrate=1535.8kbits/s speed= 219x`